# Diff amp ac equivalent circuit confusion

Tags: differential-amplifier

In the circuit below, base of Q2 is grounded.

Even though base of Q2 is grounded in the circuit, the ac equivalent circuit(T model) seems to suggest that one end of the current source Q2 is also grounded(Dotted region)!

Does this mean \$r_e+R_E\$ are shorted by a wire?
And does the output \$v_{out}\$ equal the voltage across the current source?

I know both above statements are wrong, but I don't have a good feeling why. Any help?

---

In short:  Where is base in T model? Looks base,emitter,collector are all meeting at a point. How to interpret T model correctly? Can't we use the T model "as-it-is" in circuit analysis?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why shorted? I do not see it.

Comment: One end of Q2 current source is connected to ground. Doesn't this mean everything that is parallel to it goes 0V? @G36

Comment: Sure, but Q2 is working here as a common-base amplifier.

Comment: short like this red wire @G36 https://prnt.sc/zn8b_1cGqLdU

Comment: @G36 my textbook says \$r_e\$ is in parallel with \$R_E\$, and half the the input voltage drops across this parallel combination

Comment: From ac equivalent circuit it is clear \$r_e\$ and \$R_E\$ are in parallel, but they are also in parallel with ground wire...

Comment: Yes, this is the case.  But notice that there will be a current flow via \$r_{e2}\$. Do you see it?

Comment: @G36 is that because \$i_c=\beta i_b\$ ? so what ever the current the ground is sinking, \$\beta\$ times that flows through \$r_{e2}\$ ?

Comment: but one end of Q2 current source is grounded. how to make sense of this? shouldn't all the current flow through the base(zero resistance to ground)? I think I don't understand T model :(

Comment: See this example of a T-model https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/518032/pi-model-of-common-collector/518561#518561

Comment: Now in your case, the current will follow via in the opposite direction \$r_e2\$ ( From Vin via \$r_{e1}\$  and into  \$r_e2\$ ) the base current will be the difference between IE and IC current. But if  IC = is 0A then IE = IB. This will Turn_ON  the CCCS so the collector current will start to flow in the opposite to the marked direction. Do you see it?

Comment: yes, during the positive half of input signal, the ac current flows through \$r_{e1}\$ DOWN, then through \$r_{e2}\$ UP, and then through Q2 current source UP. but still the thing that is throwing me off is  the wire connected to ground at Q2 current source...

Comment: that ground connected to Q2 current source is the ac reference point 0V right?

Comment: Yes, but the IE current is the current that controls IC current. So as long as IE is flowing IC also must flow too.

Comment: @G36 wow I see now what you mean, that wire is not shorting anything. It is just connecting the tail resistor \$R_E\$ in parallel to \$r_{e2}\$ XD you're awesome!

Comment: then my textbook has to be wrong: https://prnt.sc/cAf3QqiFadew

Comment: in that link the equivalent circuit has ground AFTER \$r_{e2}\$. That circuit is wrong ?

Comment: But in the circuit drawn by me in the post, the ground was BEFORE \$r_{e2}\$

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Can you derive the gain expression now?

Comment: i think so... \$\frac{i_cR_c}{i_e(r_e+r_e)}\approx \frac{R_c}{2r_e}\$ Thanks again it is clear now xD

Comment: @across You can see what I develop as the large-scale answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/574402/38098). The factor, \$\tanh x = x-\frac13 x^3+\frac{2}{15}x^5-\frac{17}{315}x^7+...\$, can be simplified to \$\tanh x = x\$ in the small scale. Knowing that \$r_e^{\:'}=\frac{I_{_\text{E}}}{V_T}\$ and that \$I_{_\text{E}}=\frac12 I_{_{R_{_\text{E}}}}\$, your result follows.

Answer (score 2):

Let me show you how we can find the voltage gain for a CB stage (common-base amplifier).

The small-signal model will look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4OPqx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We can see that:

$$V_{IN} = I_{IN}* r_e $$

And that:
$$I_B + I_{IN} + I_C = 0$$
$$I_B = - I_C - I_{IN} =- \beta I_B -  I_{IN}$$

So, the base current is equal to:

$$I_B = -\frac{I_{IN}}{\beta + 1}$$

And the output voltage is

$$V_{OUT} = - I_C*R_C = -(-\frac{I_{IN}}{\beta + 1})* \beta * R_C = I_{IN}R_C * \frac{\beta}{\beta +1} $$

So, the votlage gian is:

$$\frac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}} = \frac{I_{IN}R_C * \frac{\beta}{\beta +1}}{I_{IN}* r_e} = \frac{R_C}{re}  \frac{\beta}{\beta +1}$$

No back to your circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUeS4G.png)</sup>

This time I used a slightly modified T-model. So that you can see that the emitter current controls the collector current \$I_C = I_E \times \alpha = I_E \times \frac{\beta}{\beta + 1}\$

Also notice that \$Q_1\$ is working here as an emitter follower and \$Q_2\$ is a common-base amplifier. Therefore we can find the voltage gain by inspection.

$$\frac{V_{O}}{V_{IN}} = \frac{R_E||r_{e2}}{r_{e1} + R_E||r_{e2}} \times\frac{R_C}{r_{e2}}  \frac{\beta_2}{\beta_2 +1} \approx \frac{R_C}{2r_e} $$